# Authorizing User for PostText API call for a Lex bot runtime

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, serverless, amazon-lex

I'm trying to make an AWS Lex bot that will return an intent via a lambda. I have voice recognition on the client side and I want to transcribe the voice into text, then send it to an endpoint via serverless and receive that intent.  All of this works, but when integrating serverless and the aws-sdk, I'm having trouble.

The error I'm getting is

```
ERROR   AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::387496244796:assumed-role/voice-dev-us-east-1-lambdaRole/voice-dev-sendTranscript is not authorized to perform: lex:PostText on resource: arn:aws:lex:us-east-1:387496244796:bot:VoiceRecognitionBot:dev
    at Object.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)
    at Request.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/rest_json.js:55:8)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12) {
  code: 'AccessDeniedException',
  time: 2021-06-03T22:39:31.171Z,
  requestId: 'db61b680-dc93-40f1-8ac8-485aa857b5a6',
  statusCode: 403,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 22.72147780759437
}
```

I took a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50909322/4126418) but it doesn't seem like I'm doing anything different in terms of sending a `userId`. I'm not using facebook messenger or any service of the sort. This is a userId from our own app.

This is my handler:

```js
"use strict";
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

module.exports.sendTranscript = async (event, context, callback) => {
  const lexService = new AWS.LexRuntime();
  const params = {
    botAlias: "dev",
    botName: "VoiceRecognitionBot",
    inputText: event.transcript,
    userId: event.userId,
  };

  const results = await lexService
    .postText(params, (error, data) => {
      if (error) console.error(error);
      else console.log("DATA RESPONSE => ", data);
    })
    .promise();

  callback(null, results);
};
```

it's catching an error and it's basically what the log is above.

here is my sample input:

```
{"transcript": "chat with team", "userId": "920bfg83-95af-423c-a058-8f58b23487r6"}
```

Could it be my `serverless.yml`? I havent touched it besides renaming functions. No IAM roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is because of lambda don’t have correct role to execute lex post text. Refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/security_iam_id-based-policy-examples.html

Assign lex read role to lambda and try again it should work.